# Xcode fails to find file, but file is included in target

Tags: ios, xcode

When I cmd-click on the file, Xcode displays the `?` popup indicating that Xcode is unable to find the file. I'm sure that the file is in the target. I've cleaned and deleted derived data. What else could be the issue? (Xcode 9.4)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it is referenced to some place and not included there, try checking that location/target to see if the header file is located there or not by right clicking on it in xcode and clicking on "Show in Finder".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Bfc.jpg)